# \Small and \SMALL latex font size commands

Tags: fonts, size

A well-known book about LaTeX has a font-size table that contains several font-size commands including  the following three: \Small and \SMALL and \small. \small is a standard Latex command that works. I tried the other two in my document but they did not work. Does anyone know what’s going on? Where did \Small and \SMALL come from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which book? Please name it.

Comment: `\Tiny`, `\SMALL`, `\Small` are defined in `amsart` and `amsbook` classes.

Comment: Thank you! That explains it. I did not load either of those packages.